# What is meant by a new heaven and new earth?

Tags: heaven, new-earth

I often hear people talking about going to heaven but it seems more like we are destined for a new earth..

From my understanding in John's revelation, the afterlife consists of a new heavens and a new earth, and we end up on the new earth, where God dwells.

> (Rev 21:1)  And I saw a new heaven and a new earth: for the first
>   heaven and the first earth were passed away; and there was no more
>   sea.
>
> (Rev 21:2)  And I John saw the holy city, new Jerusalem, coming down
>   from God out of heaven, prepared as a bride adorned for her husband.
>
> (Rev 21:3)  And I heard a great voice out of heaven saying, Behold,
>   the tabernacle of God is with men, and he will dwell with them, and
>   they shall be his people, and God himself shall be with them, and be
>   their God.

What did John mean when he said "new heaven" and "new earth" in this passage?

Comment: What kind of believers?

Comment: @Anonymous the ones who's names are not blotted out the book of life and miss the great white throne judgement

Comment: What makes you think that "The new heaven and the new earth" are literal? What makes you think they are different than heaven?

Comment: @Flimzy I think the asker needs to state his or her own denomination. :)

Comment: Well, not necessarily *their* denomination, but the denomination from which they want an answer. But more generally, the question shows a huge lack of understanding. A much better question, IMO, would be "What is meant by a new heaven and new earth?"  The question is worded as a trap... not as an opportunity to learn.

Comment: @Flimzy I have updated the wording, sorry if it wasn't phrased correctly.

Comment: @Nikos: It is improved. I have done a small edit to narrow the question even further. I hope you don't object.

Answer (score 2):

Because the Father is said to be in heaven, in the Lord's Prayer (Matthew 6:9) and elsewhere. And in John 14:2 Jesus says:

> In my Father's house are many mansions: if it were not so, I would have told you. I go to prepare a place for you.

Thus it is rather reasonably assumed that Jesus went to prepare us a place in heaven itself.

Also Matthew's constant use of the phrase "Kingdom of Heaven" plays a part in this, as probably does 1 Thess 4:17 "Then we which are alive and remain shall be caught up together with them in the clouds, to meet the Lord in the air: and so shall we ever be with the Lord."

And because those who die before the New Jerusalem descends from the New Heaven to the New Earth in the book of Revelation, are probably in heaven in the meantime.  In Revelation itself, John places Christian martyrs in heaven by stating they are "under the altar" in heaven. (Revelation 6:9)

Also, Jude 1:14 "...Behold, the Lord cometh with ten thousands of his saints,...."  but cometh from where?  2 Thess 1:7 "And to you who are troubled rest with us, when the Lord Jesus shall be revealed from heaven with his mighty angels,..."   So that would indicate these ten thousands of saints are with him in heaven prior to his second coming.

Comment: Great answer! It remains to be seen how our time will be split up between the two domains :)

Comment: another verse that is interesting is the beggar who ends up in **paradise**, which may or may not be heaven itself.

Comment: Nowdays we are in a position that our forefathers were not, of going over the NT with a fine toothed comb.  They were lucky if they even got the gospels or a gospel harmony in their mother tongue, much less the whole NT. So the fine distinctions between paradise and heaven, and so on, weren't on their minds like they might be ours.  That's another possible answer.

Comment: there clearly a lot going on in heaven all the time, can you imagine what the new one will be like..? the current one seems pretty good don't you think :)

Answer (score 0):

The  earth  as  we  know  it  now  will  be  destroyed.

2 Peter 3;7  But  the  heavens  and  earth,  which  are  now,  by  the  same  word  are  kept  in  store,  reserved  unto  fire  against  the  day  of  judgement  and  perdition  of  ungodly  men.
Matthew 24;37-43  As  it  was  in  the  days  of  Noah,  so  shall  also  the  coming  of  the  Son  of  man  be,  For  as  in  the  days  that  were  before the flood  they  were  eating  and  drinking,  marrying  and  giving in marriage,  until the  day  that  Noah  entered  into  the  ark,  And  knew  not  until  the  flood  came,  and  took  them  all way;  so  shall  also  the  coming  of the  Son  of  man  be.

The  destruction  of  the  earth  occurs  at  the  day  of  the  LORD.  2 Peter 3;10  But  the  day  of  the  LORD  will  come as  a  theif  in  the  night;  in  which
  the  heavens  shall  pass  away  with  a  great noise,  and  the  elements  will  melt  with  fervent  heat;  the  earth  also  and  the  works  that  are  therein  shall  be   burned  up.

Isaiah  65;17  For  behold,  I  create  a  new  heaven  and  new  earth;  and  the  former  shall  not  be  remembered,  nor  come  into  mind.
Revelation 21;7  He  that  overcometh  shall  inherit  all  things,  and  I  will  be  his  God  and  he  shall  be  my  son.
Revelation 22;14  Blessed  are  they  that  do  his  commandments,  that  they  may  have  right  to  the  tree  of  life  and    may  enter  in  through  the  gates  into  the  city.